# Hibernate extend entity for same table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table with two fields
I would like to have two objects.

First one only has field1

```
@Entity(name = "simpleTableObject")
@Table(name = "someTable")
public class SimpleTableObject
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "field1")
    private String field1;
```

Second one has all two fields

```
@Entity(name = "tableObject")
@Table(name = "someTable")
public class TableObject
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "field1")
    private String field1;

    @Column(name = "field2")
    private String field2;
```

I load each one using

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List get(Class aClass)
{
    ClassMetadata hibernateMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(aClass);
    if (hibernateMetadata == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (hibernateMetadata instanceof AbstractEntityPersister)
    {
        AbstractEntityPersister persister = (AbstractEntityPersister) hibernateMetadata;
        String                  tableName = persister.getTableName();
        if (tableName != null)
        {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
                    createQuery("from " + tableName).list();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I would like to do is have `TableObject` extend `SimpleTableObject`. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: From your question it is not clear whether `SimpleTableObject` and `TableObject` might point to the same record in the table or are table records somehow separated into two different entities? In the first case, what do you expect to happen when new `SimpleTableObject` is saved to the table? And how do you expect caching to work?

Comment: @SergGr Both will point to the same record in the table. they will be used for reading mainly (there will pretty much be no saving). Additionally table has default values, so if need ever comes to it, I can save, and fields that were not mentioned will just have defaults values filled in. That should be possible no? So if SimpleTableObject is saved then field4 and field 5 will just have default value filled in that is specified in mysql table creation query.

Comment: You still forget that Hibernate implements some caching of the loaded data and having 2 different entities mapped to the same table will mess up with it quite seriously. I strongly advice you against doing so. Why couldn't you load just `TableObject` from Hibernate and convert `SimpleTableObject` to a DTO easily mapped from the actual entities? Why do you need `SimpleTableObject` to be a superclass?

Comment: I agree with @SergGr. If you don't persist SimpleTableObject separately, I would assume you don't need the SimpleTableObject to be mapped as an entity. It can be created by passing in a TableObject.

Comment: @Simon is it not possible to have `TableObject` extend `SimpleTableObject` and have both of them read from the same table? I want to send `SimpleTableObject` through network (which is why it needs less data), and I want to use `TableObject` on server side. This is basic java inheritance, is it really absolutely not possible?

Comment: First of all, it's much better to return an empty list instead of `null` values.

Comment: @rebelizant what's second of all?

Comment: @Quillion second of all is the answer posted below :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want save common fields in your required tables means suppose you have class A  and B and you have some common filed like created_by,updated_by and you want to save field1,field2 in both entity:
IN database level:

```
query> select * from A;
+----++------------------------+
| id | created_by | updated_by |
+----+------------+------------+
|  3 |    xyz     | abc        |
+----+------------+------------+
query> select * from B;
 +----++------------------------+
| id | created_by | updated_by |
+----+------------+------------+
|  3 |    xyz     | abc        |
+----+------------+------------+
```

for this type of structure you should use @MappedSuperclass as @Dragan Bozanovic suggested

But if you want Parent Child relation and want generate table per class then you can use
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
it will create table per class 
e.g: Suppose you have 2 class Payment and CreditCard, Payment is parent class for CreditCard.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Payment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double amount;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}


@Entity
public class CreditCard extends Payment {
private String ccNumber;
private Date expireDate;

    public String getCcNumber() {
        return ccNumber;
    }

    public void setCcNumber(String ccNumber) {
        this.ccNumber = ccNumber;
    }

    public Date getExpireDate() {
        return expireDate;
    }

    public void setExpireDate(Date expireDate) {
        this.expireDate = expireDate;
    }
}
```

Now you will save date :

```
public class TestConcreteClasses {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Payment payment = new Payment();
        payment.setAmount(52.6);
        createData(payment);
        CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
        creditCard.setAmount(10);
        creditCard.setCcNumber("2536985474561236");
        creditCard.setExpireDate(new Date());
        createData(creditCard);

    }

    private static void createData(Payment instance) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(instance);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

then data will save like

```
query> select * from Payment;
+----+--------+
| id | amount |
+----+--------+
|  1 |   52.6 |
+----+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

 select * from CreditCard;
+----+--------+------------------+---------------------+
| id | amount | ccNumber         | expireDate          |
+----+--------+------------------+---------------------+
|  2 |     10 | 2536985474561236 | 2017-03-12 14:10:15 |
+----+--------+------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are 3 types of inheritance used in hibernate, here is hibernate doc for inheritance
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/InheritanceType.html, you should pick any of them according to your requirement.

Comment: My bounty was about to expire. I haven't had a chance to try what you suggested, however I have a feeling that it will work

Comment: @bhushan-uniyal, You should have mentioned that TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy is optional (according to the JPA specification) and it may not be implemented by some JPA providers.

Comment: @rebelizant agree, but here I already have mentioned *if you want Parent Child relation and generate table per class* , also mention 3 types of inheritance used in hibernate and pick any of them if need Parent Child relation, I don't know if there is any another way to achieve  Parent Child relationship in hibernet,  Also pick up any strategy, it's totally dependent on our requirement, what kind of requirement we have for our business logic.

Comment: @bhushan-uniyal, how is this a parent-child relation? It would mean that CreditCard instance (table record) cannot exists without Payment instance (table record.

Comment: @rebelizant not, if you want just save CreditCard then you don't need to  create Payment instrument instance. Payment is parent of CridetCard so all the property of Parent inherit in CreditCard.

Comment: MappedSuperclass can't be used in To relations...

Answer (score 11):

You can have a common superclass for both entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractTableObject {
 // common mappings
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "someTable")
public class TableObject extends AbstractTableObject {
 // remaining mappings
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "someTable")
@Immutable
public class SimpleTableObject extends AbstractTableObject {
 // nothing here
}
```

Additionally, you can mark the `SimpleTableObject` entity to be [`@Immutable`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html) as shown above, so that it cannot be persisted or updated accidentally.

Comment: I think this answer best addresses the question posed by the OP. Two entity types that point to the same table and table rows, with one entity having a subset of the fields contained by the other, and common fields shared through inheritance.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to do something about your question. I defined another class hierarchy: UserWithRole that extends User which is similar to yours.

### Define class `User` as an entity with inheritance strategy `SINGLE_TABLE`:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 protected Long id;
 @Column(nullable = false)
 protected String name;
 // toString(), default constructor, setters/getters, more constructors.
 ...
}
```

This inheritance strategy has one considerable disadvantage:

- Subclasses can't contain non-nullable columns.

There is another strategy `JOINED` that allows creating non-nullable columns in subclasses. It creates an additional table for each subclass these tables have FK to the superclass table.

### Define `UserWithRole` class:

```java
@Entity
public class UserWithRole extends User {
  private String role;
  // toString(), default constructor, setters/getters, more constructors.
 ...
}
```

### Add `Helper` class to create users in the database and use your query:

```java
@Component
public class Helper {
 @Autowired
 EntityManager entityManager;
 @Transactional
 public void createUsers() {
  for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   User user;
   if (i % 2 == 0) {
    user = new UserWithRole("User-" + i, "Role-" + i);
   } else {
    user = new User("User-" + i);
   }
   entityManager.persist(user);
  }
  entityManager.flush();
 }

 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public < T > List < T > get(Class < T > aClass) {
  SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
  ClassMetadata hibernateMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(aClass);
  if (hibernateMetadata == null) {
   return null;
  }
  if (hibernateMetadata instanceof AbstractEntityPersister) {
   AbstractEntityPersister persister = (AbstractEntityPersister) hibernateMetadata;
   String entityName = persister.getEntityName();

   if (entityName != null) {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
    createQuery("from " + entityName).list();
   }
  }
  return null;
 }

}
```

As you may see, I changed your method a bit:

- Added generic type to avoid unsafe type casts;
- Used entity name instead of table name because HQL expects entity name.

### Let's start testing

#### Get all `User` instances:

```
@Test
public void testQueryUsers() {
 helper.createUsers();
 for (User user: helper.get(User.class)) {
  System.out.println(user);
 }
}
```

Output (users with role are still `UserWithProfile` instances at runtime):

```
UserWithRole{id=1, name='User-0', role='Role-0'}
User{id=2, name='User-1'}
UserWithRole{id=3, name='User-2', role='Role-2'}
User{id=4, name='User-3'}
UserWithRole{id=5, name='User-4', role='Role-4'}
User{id=6, name='User-5'}
UserWithRole{id=7, name='User-6', role='Role-6'}
User{id=8, name='User-7'}
UserWithRole{id=9, name='User-8', role='Role-8'}
User{id=10, name='User-9'}
```

SQL query issued by Hibernate:

```
select
user0_.id as id2_0_,
 user0_.name as name3_0_,
 user0_.role as role4_0_,
 user0_.dtype as dtype1_0_
from
users user0_
```

#### Get all `UserWithProfile` instances:

```
@Test
public void testQueryUsersWithProfile() {
 helper.createUsers();
 for (User user: helper.get(UserWithRole.class)) {
  System.out.println(user);
 }
}
```

Output:

```
UserWithRole{id=1, name='User-0', role='Role-0'}
UserWithRole{id=3, name='User-2', role='Role-2'}
UserWithRole{id=5, name='User-4', role='Role-4'}
UserWithRole{id=7, name='User-6', role='Role-6'}
UserWithRole{id=9, name='User-8', role='Role-8'}
```

SQL query issued by Hibernate:

```
select
userwithro0_.id as id2_0_,
 userwithro0_.name as name3_0_,
 userwithro0_.role as role4_0_
from
users userwithro0_
where
userwithro0_.dtype = 'UserWithRole'
```

Please, let me know if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Good question, I assume you have to look at `@MappedSuperclass` anotation. It allows to make an "abstract" entity class that would not be instantiated, however you can extend from that.

See example of that [here](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-mappedsuperclass-hibernate)

**Update:** Since you use `@Entity` anotation, you dont have to use `@Table` since Hibernate will create table named `@Entity` for you.

Comment: I need both classes to be instantiated though, since both of them will be used.

Answer (score 1):

The comment is a bit too long, so I have to write it in the answer.

Are you going to have two separate DAO to retrieve `TableObject` and `SimpleTableObject` separately?If yes, you don't need the extend, just treat them as two separate entities. If not, you can first get the TableObject and maybe create a constructor with `SimpleTableObject(TableObject)` and copy all the fields you need there. I don't think it is possible to retrieve two entities with one `findById` function. Hibernate will be confused which entity to map to with the id, which means it doesn't make much sense to have the extend. If you want to keep the consistency, how about considering SimpleTableObject as a view of TableObjec.

**UPDATE** : @Quillion I don't think it is possible this way. Since these two entities are basically identical(you can ignore some fields in an entity), there is no way for hibernate to identify which entity to map. Of course you can add an extra column as a discriminator, then use the `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` to map these two entities, but I assume this is not what you want.

Comment: I added edit to my question with more clarification. Additionally what do you mean by considering `SimpleTableObject` as a view of `TableObject`? And as a side note, I want to extend to avoid having pretty much identical objects with slightly different fields. And I do not want to do `SimpleTableObject(TableObject)` because that still defeats the purpose and doesn't end up extending

Comment: I have updated the question completely. So far what I know as a fact is that the code above works without a hitch. There has to be some way to extend `SimpleTableObject` to `TableObject`